# SimpleCursorAdapter with Checkboxes triggering always two

Tags: android, checkbox, simplecursoradapter

I created an Adapter to display contacts. It has checkboxes, but if I click on one checkbox, every 8. element gets triggered, although the OnCheckedChanged Listener get´s only fired once.

I don´t know what is wrong with my adapter, maybe the problem is caused in some methods for displaying stuff, which I propably need to overwrite first.

What could be the problem?

```
public class ContactAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter implements
    OnCheckedChangeListener {

private Context context;

private int layout;

private Cursor cursor;

public Cursor getCursor() {
    return cursor;
}

public ContactAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from,
                      int[] to, int flags) {
    super(context, layout, c, from, to, flags);
    this.context = context;
    this.layout = layout;
    cursor = c;
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    LayoutInflater vi;

    View v = convertView;

    if (v == null) {

        v = ((LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(layout, null);

        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.contactImage);
        holder.txtName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.contactName);
        holder.txtName.setTextSize(18);
        holder.checkBox = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);

        v.setTag(holder);
    }


    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
    Cursor cursor = (Cursor) getItem(position);

    String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
    holder.txtName.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME)));

    String photoID = cursor.getString(cursor
            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.PHOTO_ID));

    if (photoID != null) {
        Uri photoUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
                Long.parseLong(photoID));
        holder.imageView.setImageURI(photoUri);

    } else
        holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);


    holder.checkBox.setTag(id);
    holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

    return v;
}

@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton v, boolean isChecked) {
    //TODO
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView txtName;
    ImageView imageView;
    CheckBox checkBox;
}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because views are reused to improve performance, in your case every 8 element is getting the same view, cause is been invoked with the same `convertView`. (You can log your `convertView` variable, and you'll see this).

So, to solve the problem, you have to set the state of the checkbox elsewhere and establish it every time in your `getView` method like this:

```
holder.checkBox.setTag(id);
holder.checkBox.setChecked(mapOfStoredCheckedContacts.get(id));
holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
```

For this to work, create a variable:

```
Map<String,Boolean> mapOfStoredCheckedContacts=new HashMap<String,Boolean>
```

and keep the state in the listener like this:

```
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton v, boolean isChecked) {
    mapOfStoredCheckecContacts.put(v.getTag(),isChecked);
    //More code
}
```

Comment: But the state is stored in each checkbox itself. I don´t understand the behaviour.The position variable is always correct, as well as the id of the contact which belongs to it

Comment: @Nachbar90, I had an error in my answer, the correct variable was `convertView` not `position`. And, yes, the state is stored in checkbox itself, but since the `convertView` you are receiving is an already created view (reused), you are getting a checkbox that already has some state (perhaps already checked), so you have to set the correct state in `getView` every time.